# При каком минимальном значении N на хранение одного пароля при первом способе записи потребуется на 6 бит больше памяти

Tags: информатика

Генератор паролей создает пароли, длиной 7 символов. Каждый символ с равной вероятностью является одним из N символов алфавита, который использует генератор паролей. Есть два способа записи паролей в память:
1. Хранить код каждого символа пароля независимо, используя для этого минимальное одинаковое для всех кодов символов количество бит.
2. Хранить код пароля целиком, используя для каждого пароля минимальное одинаковое для всех кодов паролей количество бит.
При каком минимальном значении N на хранение одного пароля при первом способе записи потребуется на 6 бит больше памяти, чем при втором способе записи. В ответе укажите целое число.

Если количество бит для одного символа это log2(N) и для хранения одного пароля это log2(7^N) то логично будет следующие уравнение 7*log2(N) - N*log2(7) - 6 = 0
Но ответ не получается, возможно я составил уравнение не правильно.

Comment: А разве не K * log(N) ? log(N) - это кол-во бит, затрачиваемых на один символ пароля. Значит, чтобы получить вес пароля из 7 символов, нужно умножить вес одного символа на 7, что равняется K * log(N), где K - кол-во символов пароля, а log(N) - вес одного символа пароля.

Answer (score 1):

1. Пусть есть N символов. Тогда на 1 символ приходится i=ceil(log(N)) бит. На 1 пароль 7i бит. Мы округляем вверх до целого числа бит.
2. Пусть есть N символов. Получаем 7^N паролей. Тогда на 1 пароль приходится Nlog(7)=3N бит. Мы округляем вверх до целого числа бит.

   ```
   7i-3N=6
   7i=6+3N
   7i=3(2+N)
   ```

следовательно для наименьшего i = 3, а 2+N=7, откуда N=5.